# Unsubscribe link not shown in gmail

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, email-client, unsubscribe

Am sending a mail to gmail.com with a header.

```
MimeMessage.addHeader("List-Unsubscribe","<http://www.example.com>");
```

Eventhough the header is present in original content of the mail, unsubscribe link is not shown in mail. Kindly advice.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding from [Google Support Link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#unsub) you need to have prepare some conditions like your try and [Amazon Recommendation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-fields.html) but finally google decided for show unsubscribed link in top of your emails.

Also, based on [Official Gmail Blog](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2009/07/unsubscribing-made-easy.html):

> This only works for some senders right now. We're actively encouraging
>   senders to support auto-unsubscribe — we think 100% should. We won't
>   provide the unsubscribe option on messages from spammers: we can't
>   trust that they'll actually unsubscribe you, and they might even send
>   you more spam. So you'll only see the unsubscribe option for senders
>   that we're pretty sure are not spammers and will actually honor your
>   unsubscribe request. We're being pretty conservative about which
>   senders to trust in the beginning; over time, we hope to offer the
>   ability to unsubscribe from more email.

Answer (score -3):

How did you expect it to be shown?  Where did you look for it?

Gmail, like most mail readers, doesn't show raw headers.  It shows the header information it thinks is relevant.  If you want to see the raw headers, there should be a "view source" or "show headers" operation to see them.  If you view the message source, and this header is not present, then some mail server has removed it.

Comment: I checked the 'show original' option in gmail. its shows my List-Unsubscribe url.

Comment: But the unsubscribe button/link is displayed in mail message. why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.  It's being displayed but you **don't** want it to be displayed?  What exactly is happening and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to show unsubscribe link in my email. After a study, setting email header 'List-Unsubscribe:<mailto:example@test.com>, <http://www.google.com>' will do the work. I did it in my code and sent sample mail to my gmail. Unsubscribe link is not shown. Then i tried the view the header through 'Show original' and found my header.

Comment: Is DKIM signature is mandatory for email clients to show unsubscribe link?

Comment: I doubt it.  I don't know any way to make the unsubscribe link in the header show up.  If you have an example where it shows up, please post a screenshot.